# How to align vertically different fonts in paintListener

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I have custom paint widget and I must draw some text with different font sizes.
Example:

```
paintListener = new PaintListener() {
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        int verticalOffset = 10;
        Font smallFont = SWTResourceManager.getFont("", 8, SWT.BOLD);
        e.gc.setFont(smallFont);
        String text1 = "test1";
        Point text1Size = e.gc.textExtent(text1);
        e.gc.drawText(text1, 0, e.y - text1Size.y - verticalOffset);

        Font bigFont = SWTResourceManager.getFont("", 12, SWT.NONE);
        e.gc.setFont(bigFont);
        String text2 = "test2";
        Point text2Size = e.gc.textExtent(text2);
        e.gc.drawText(text2, e.x - text2Size.x, e.y - text2Size.y - verticalOffset);
    }
}
```

I wonder how to align this two texts vertically or if it is possible to compute distance between area returned by textExtent and font baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `FontMetrics` for the current font from the `GC`:

```
ec.gc.setFont(xxxx);

FontMetrics metrics = e.gc.getFontMetrics();
```

`FontMetrics` has `getDescent()` `getHeight()` ... methods which will allow you to adjust the drawing position.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for! I spend a lot of time googling for it.